# PDF from UIScrollView is blank

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiscrollview, core-graphics

I have a UIScrollView which I want to export to a PDF file. The scroll view contains another view (content view) which actually contains the visible content:

```
scrollView : UIScrollView
-> contentView : UIView
   -> view1 : UIView
      ...
   -> view2 : UIView
      ...
   ...
```

The code for the PDF export is:

```c
func generatePDFData() -> NSData {
    // I first tried to use the scroll view but the result was the same
    let bounds = contentView.bounds

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, bounds, nil)

    let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(pdfContext, kCGInterpolationMedium)
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(pdfContext, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, nil)

    // without the following two settings, the result remains the same
    CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext,1.0,-1.0)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext,0.0,-bounds.size.height)

    contentView.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext)

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    return pdfData
}
```

I then use the data to generate a PDF file. The resulting file has a size of about 120 KB, so I expect it to contain some stuff (the view does not comprise any images). However, when I try to open it, I just get a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your only problem is beginning new pdf page in a context. Replace `CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, nil)` with `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()` and everything should work.

Comment: Additionally, `CGContextScaleCTM ` and `CGContextTranslateCTM ` need to be called before `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()` takes place. Otherwise, the options have no effect on the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
contentView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
```

Comment: This does not change anything.